# Linear Algebra Self Study

Tags: linear-algebra, self-learning

I'm currently a high school student with a love for math. I have taken Plane and Coordinate Geometry, both Algebra I and II, Trigonometry, and am halfway done with Calc A.

I want to major in quantum physics, and feel that a background with linear algebra would help. As there are no courses available at my school, I must self study.

What seems most promising is the MIT OCW course along with the accompanying textbook. Would there be a better book/online resource for teaching myself? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I don't think you can do much better than Gilbert Strang's introduction. His book is also heavy on interesting applications that you will most likely come across again in your physics studies.

Answer (score 1):

I'm in a similar situation, and I learn linear algebra from Axler's text, "Linear Algebra Done Right." The problem sets are very nice and I really like the book; it's very easy to understand and explanations are lucid.

The MIT OCW course uses Strang's text, I believe, which I'm not familiar with.